# NoSQL worthwhile usage

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

Recently I have encountered the concept of `NoSQL` and as far as I manage to comprehend is good for dealing with huge amount of data.

My question is, what is the limit were using `NoSQL` becomes worthwhile ? Is it only for companies which handle really huge amount of data like Google, Facebook etc. or it's worth the trouble to switching to it from a SQL database even for a smaller data amount .

Comment: SQL databases are also good at dealing with huge amount of data, that's what they are explicitly designed for. The threshold you are asking about does not exist, because the distinction between SQL and NoSQL databases is not what you believe it is.

Comment: @lanzz Ok. So when does NoSQL is worth using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder what "concept of NoSQL" you mean, because it is an umbrella term for a wide field of different database technologies. The only thing they have in common is what sets them apart from each other: they are "not (only) SQL". They have widely different philosophies, use-cases and target groups.

Just to give you an overview, here are a few of the large factions of NoSQL databases.

There are **document-based databases** like MongoDB or CouchDB. Their advantage is that they do not require a consistent data structure. They are useful when your requirements and thus your database layout changes constantly, or when you are dealing with datasets which belong together but still look very differently. When you have a lot of tables with two columns called "key" and "value", then these might be worth looking into.

There are **graph databases** like Neo4j or GiraffeDB. Their focus is at defining data by its relation to other data. When you have a lot of tables with primary keys which are the primary keys of two other tables (and maybe some data describing the relation between them), then these might be something for you.

Then you have simple **key-value stores** like MemcacheDB, Cassandra or Google's BigTable. They are very simplistic, but that makes them fast and easy to use. When you have no need for stored procedures, constraints, triggers and all those advanced database features and you just want fast storage and retrieval of your data, then those are for you.

And these are just a few facets of the new database world.

But there is still one sector where relational databases excel, and that's when it comes to following the ACID principle. Most NoSQL databases don't fully guarantee all four of these:

- Atomic transactions (chains of commands which are processed together, n-order and all-or-none)
- Consistent database schema with constraints and triggers which ensure that garbage data can not exist in the database.
- Isolation of transactions - transactions which are guaranteed to be unaffected by others which happen at the same time.
- Durability - safety from data-loss even in case of a sudden system crash*

(* to be fair, most of the databases listed above are indeed pretty durable, especially those which are easy to set up as redundant fail-over clusters.